# Adding a jQuery delay on autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a jQuery autocomplete for an application:

```
$("#search-input").on('keyup', function() {
    search = $(this).val();
    autocomplete_div = $(".autocomplete")
    $.get('/ajax/search/', {'search': search,}, function(response){
        autocomplete_div.html(response)
    });
});
```

What would I need to add to the above code to add a 400ms delay?

Comment: well, considering that the code snippet uses deprecated features such as `live()` I wouldn't add anything to it. I'd start over

Comment: you shouldn't use live but `.on()` (depending jQuery version) and shouldn't use keydown event but keyup instead and then delay request using a timeout and debounce it using clearTimeout

Comment: @A.Wolff I made those two changes. How would I add a timeout and then clearTimeout? Could you please show me in an answer?

Comment: Beware here you aren't delegating event as your original post was using live. See DOC for syntax to delegate event using `.on()` or check my answer

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // your code here
}, 400);
```

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) is a method provided by the browser's `window` object.

A more complete example that cancels a timer if already set using [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout) would be:

```
var myTimer = 0;

$("#search-input").on('keydown', function() {
    search = $(this).val();

    // cancel any previously-set timer
    if (myTimer) {
        clearTimeout(myTimer);
    }

    myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        autocomplete_div = $(".autocomplete")
        $.get('/ajax/search/', {'search': search,}, function(response){
            autocomplete_div.html(response)
        });
    }, 400);
});
```

Also note use of `on` instead of the deprecated `live`.

Comment: Could you please show how that would be integrated into the above code? Just so I'm clear on where it should be put. Thanks.

Comment: Updated with more complete example.

Answer (score 4):

Your code should look like this: (for jQuery 1.7+)

```
$(document).on('keyup', "#search-input", function () {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
    var _self = this;
    $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function () {
        $.get('/ajax/search/', {
            search: _self.value
        }, function (response) {
            $(".autocomplete").html(response);
        });
    }, 400));
});
```

If using older jQuery version, use `live()` or better `delegate()`. BTW, you should bind it to closest static container, not `document`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setTimeout() function to delay the start of the expression, in this case, your function.  Beware that this does not delay processing beyond this code.  It will only delay the start of this function, while continuing to process code after the function.

```
$("#search-input").live('keydown', setTimeout(function() {
    search = $(this).val();
    autocomplete_div = $(".autocomplete")
    $.get('/ajax/search/', {'search': search,}, function(response){
        autocomplete_div.html(response)
    })
},400));
```

EDITED: to correct misplaced parentheses.