# How to delay validation for jquery validate plugin for on key up event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using jquery validate for my web site. I disabled validation onkeyup.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#emailrecheckform").validate({onkeyup:false});
    });
```

I want to know how to delay validation of jquery validate for on key up event. I did not find anything useful on internet.

Comment: delay how? calling another function first? not by a set emount of milisecs? why do you need to delay it ? need more info!

Comment: I am using it in Remote validation mvc. MVC remotevalidation sends requests per every keyup to the server. I want to slow it down to minimize bussiness to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deal with this problem many times. The problem is a request is sended to the server every time we press a key, so we need the function be called after some time the user press the key. This will do the trick :

```
 var myTimer = 0;

 $("#emailrecheckform").on('keydown', function() {
  // cancel any previously-set timer
    if (myTimer) {
       clearTimeout(myTimer);
    }

     myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
       alert("sending request : " + $("#search-input").val());
     }, 400); //delay time in milliseconds
  });
```

based on :

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568999/adding-a-jquery-delay-on-autocomplete)